# Removing Null Values from Multiple Columns

Tags: mysql

How do I remove rows with columns that have ALL null values?

Table example:

```
CustID    DOB     Order1  Order2  Order3  Order4
  1       xxx      NULL    NULL    NULL     NULL 
  2       xxx      25       32      27       5
  3       xxx      NULL     6       NULL     3
  4       xxx       1      NULL     NULL     NULL
  5       xxx      NULL    NULL     NULL     NULL
```

I would like to delete the rows for custID 1 and 5.  Anything with a value in any of the 4 order columns should be kept.

Can I achieve this in my where statement?

Comment: Where order1=null and order2=null and...

Comment: The actual problem here is that you need to normalize your table design.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
DELETE FROM 
  'your_table' 
WHERE 
  'order1 IS NULL
  AND 'order2' IS NULL
  AND 'order3' IS NULL
  AND 'order4' IS NULL
  AND 'order5' IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always use the direct approach: check each field against `NULL` individually, summarize the results with `AND`. Just remember to use either `IS NULL` comparison operator, or `ISNULL()` expression; comparing a value to `NULL` using `=` **always yields false**:

```
DELETE FROM Customers
WHERE Order1 IS NULL 
  AND Order2 IS NULL...
```

An alternative would be using [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function, which *returns the first non-NULL value in the list, or NULL if there are no non-NULL values*:

```
DELETE FROM Customers
WHERE COALESCE(Order1, Order2, Order3, Order4) IS NULL
```

The bottom line, though, is that you might need to think twice about the structure of your `Customers` table, probably spending some time on reorganizing the relationship between Orders and Customers. One possible solution is adding a CustomerId into Order entity.

Answer (score 0):

Specify your null-checks in your selection clause (the "WHERE" part of your query).

```
DELETE FROM my_table
WHERE order1 is null
    AND order2 is null
    AND order3 is null
    AND order4 is null
```

Answer (score 0):

This will only delete the null entries with union relation, the above mentioned picture can be done by replacing the AND with OR to perform the intersection

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).